# libevent during file deletion/modification

Tags: c, linux, asynchronous, file-descriptor, libevent

Is to possible to use libevent to monitor a file removal/update?

Assuming that /var/log/file.1 is removed I want to report it in my program. Is this possible? If yes, how?

My operating system is Linux and I want to create a demon that fires messages during some operating system actions.

Where can I find more information?

Comment: You can look the source of tail (-f and -F) which are able to tell if a file was truncated. IIRC, they use `select(2)`

Comment: accepted the inotify solution, looks very close to what I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is particularly targeted for Linux, you can make use of the [`inotify(7)`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) facility instead. It has a very simple programming interface and is meant to monitor file changes and deletions, while the purpose of `libevent` is slightly different: to watch over a group of descriptors and be notified whenever any of them is ready for reading/writing.

I am not sure if `libevent` wraps `inotify` at all, because similar facilities are not provided by all other OS'es `libevent` supports.

Answer (score 0):

just using some simple logic you can check whether this file is deleted or not ?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct stat st = {0};

if (stat("/var/log/file.1", &st) == -1) {
    printf("file is deleted or not present");
}
```

you can also check more property of file by checking another element of struct stat